# SpringBootTest in one module doesn't see Application class in another

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa

Let's say I have a project with structure like this:

```
my-app
  +-- pom.xml
+-- runtime
  +-- src.main.java.mypackage
    +-- Application.java
  +-- pom.xml
+-- library
  +-- src.main.java.mypackage.repository
    +-- MyRepository.java
  +-- src.test.java.mypackage.repository
    +-- MyRepositoryTest.java
  +-- pom.xml
```

In my `runtime` `pom.xml` there is a dependency to the `library` and other stuff, necessary to run spring boot application:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mypackage</groupId>
        <artifactId>library</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The `library` `pom.xml` has a `spring-boot-starter-test`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Application works just fine, but `MyRepositoryTest` doesn't work since it can't see the runtime module and therefore the Application class itself. I can't put dependency to a `library` pom.xml since it would result to a cyclic dependency.

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EntityScan
public class Application {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**MyRepositoryTest.java**

```
@SpringBootTest
class MyRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository tested;

    @Test
    void test() {
        ...
    }
```

How do I setup Spring Boot multi-module application with a @SpringBootTest in the `library` module?